# Php operator that evaluates TRUE on a answer typo

Tags: php, operators

I am busy building an ELO for some students in primary education.

Some questions in the ELO are 'open', so students should type the answer in a textbox.

Suppose there is a question where the correct answer is "scanner". A student makes a typo and types "scaner". I don't want to mark this answer as incorrect.

So I wonder if there is an operator 'resembles' in PHP, same as `LIKE` in MariaDb Sql or the double 'tilde' in math.

I am quite sure there are workarounds for my 'problem', but I'm just eager to learn.

Comment: Seems difficult to make a general algorithm, since some words differ by only one letter but have completely different meanings. See discussion here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217698/words-that-change-meaning-when-a-letter-is-added-removed-changed.

Comment: while i suck at spelling and grammar. if the answer is wrong, it's wrong.

Comment: @Svea I agree, a general algorithm is a bit difficult. Comparisons like `instillation` vs `installation` will always be the bane of something like this. However, in such a niche situation, I do think that an algorithm that works won't be hard to find. Other circumstances may yield undesired results, but for this application it seems OP could easily find a viable solution.

Comment: Agreed. Pragmatically each answer should be reviewed to rule out antonyms (they seem to be called this in the supplied link). If ok, then I would go for e.g. levenShtein. I've upped the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

The Levenshtein algorithm is GREAT for this exact scenario. It works well with typos or brain-fart moments like typing "blew" instead of "blue", names, etc.

Levenshtein will return a number. This number indicates the "distance" between two words. What I'd do in your scenario, is make a maximum distance with a small number, like 2 or 3. That way, if there is only one character correction necessary, it'll be fine. However, if the word is "Scanner", and they input "Skammer", it would not actually pass that as a valid response.

Here are a few examples:

```
<?php

$threshold = 2;

$words = array('Scanner', 'Scaner', 'Skanner', 'Skammer', 'Clammer',     'Skaner');
$match = "Scanner";

foreach($words as $word){
    echo levenshtein($match, $word) . "<br>";
}
```

The above will output the following:

```
0
1
1
3
4
2
```

So you can see the correlation there between the closely related words, and the not-so closely related words. So, with the above threshold, if we change our code just a bit we can do something like this:

```
<?php

$threshold = 2;

$words = array('Scanner', 'Scaner', 'Skanner', 'Skammer', 'Clammer', 'Skaner');
$match = "Scanner";

foreach($words as $word){
    if(levenshtein($match, $word) <= $threshold) echo "$word is close enough to $match! <br>";
        else echo "$word is NOT close enough to $match! <br>";
}
```

We'll get a response like this:

```
Scanner is close enough to Scanner! 
Scaner is close enough to Scanner! 
Skanner is close enough to Scanner! 
Skammer is NOT close enough to Scanner! 
Clammer is NOT close enough to Scanner! 
Skaner is close enough to Scanner!
```

Notice how "Clammer" is a distance of 4 from "Scanner". Let me explain this just a bit. That distance is the amount of characters that would have to change in order for the word to match. So, "C" has to change, "L" has to change, and both "M"s have to change. Thus, a score of 4.

When using this, please consider that "S" and "s" are two totally different characters, so it absolutely is case sensitive. I'd make it case-insensitive to make absolutely sure that something like "ScAnNeR" doesn't get marked as an incorrect answer. Like so:

```
<?php

$threshold = 2;

$words = array('ScAnNeR', 'Scaner', 'Skanner', 'Skammer', 'Clammer', 'Skaner');
$match = "Scanner";

foreach($words as $word){
    if(levenshtein(strtolower($match), strtolower($word)) <= $threshold) echo "$word is close enough to $match! <br>";
        else echo "$word is NOT close enough to $match! <br>";
}
```

**Words of Caution**

I *highly* advise not relying on `soundex()`. Check out this example:

```
<?php

$threshold = 2;

$words = array('spectacular', 'spectacle');
$match = "spectacle";

foreach($words as $word){
    if(levenshtein(strtolower($match), strtolower($word)) <= $threshold) echo "$word is close enough to $match! <br>";
        else echo "$word is NOT close enough to $match! <br>";

    echo soundex($word) . "/" . soundex($match) . "<br>";
}
```

That example gives this result:

```
spectacular is NOT close enough to spectacle! 
S123/S123
spectacle is close enough to spectacle! 
S123/S123
```

Two totally separate words that don't even sound alike, and they would have been a perfect match according to `soundex()`! While I think it's a useful function for some applications, it is not a good enough solution for this kind of application. Here, another example:

```
<?php

$threshold = 2;

$words = array('clancy', 'klancy');
$match = "clancy";

foreach($words as $word){
if(levenshtein(strtolower($match), strtolower($word)) <= $threshold) echo "$word is close enough to $match! <br>";
        else echo "$word is NOT close enough to $match! <br>";

    echo soundex($word) . "/" . soundex($match) . "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
clancy is close enough to clancy! 
C452/C452
klancy is close enough to clancy! 
K452/C452
```

Bottom line: *Don't rely on `soundex()` for this kind of application. You will only end up fighting with it and get burnt in the process.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `similar_text()` native to PHP. Information can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

What's interesting is that you pass a variable by reference for the last parameter. So you would do something like:

`similar_text($first, $second, $percent)`

And you can specify a `$percent` to a threshold for acceptance. So if they are similar to X%, you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a test, I personally would require correct spelling with no typos, however there are two good possibilities, [soundex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) and [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php):

```
var_dump(
    soundex('scanner') == soundex('scaner')
);
```

Yields `true`.

```
var_dump(
    strlen('scanner') - similar_text('scanner', 'scaner')
);
```

Yields `1` so you would need to decide how many differences are acceptable.

Another more complex possibility is [levenshtein()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), though deciding an appropriate distance based on very different supposedly correct answers will be a task.